# Heroku: puppeteer chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libX11-xcb.so.1

Tags: reactjs, react-snap

I get following error when deploying app with `react-snap` to Heroku.

```
puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686378/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libX11-xcb.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I applied all the changes, set all the buildpacks.

I even could react the the first deploy without  `"postbuild": "react-snap"` line, it workes.

But then adding lines here, will fail again. What now?

```
"reactSnap": {
    "cacheAjaxRequests": true,
    "inlineCss": true,
    "http2PushManifest": true,
    "puppeteerArgs": ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"]
  }
```

```
"postbuild": "react-snap"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I struggled with this issue for 4 hours.
Googled a lot of solutions but no one worked for me.
And finally I've got it !!! (Actually, it is now at this very moment)

Heroku log:

> ```
>    > individual-claims@0.1.0 postbuild /tmp/build_3cc3bffa_
>    > react-snap
>    
>    ✅  crawled 1 out of 1 (/)
> ```

Done! I am happy.

## Solution:

1. Go to Heroku Settings -> Buildpacks -> Add buildpack
2. Add: https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack.git

IMPORTANT !!! **Make sure this is the first one.** That's the common fault.
When making React on Heroku you already (I suppose) have
https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git
But react-buildpack should be the second one. Nobody says it.

3. Redeploy and have fun.

*Note:* After a lot of struggling I've made some changes to my application (I don't think this is really important, however)

1. in package.json

```
     "engines": {
          "node": ">=14.12.0",  // Just to make sure I have the latest and the greatest 
          "npm": ">=6.14.8"
        },
  
   "devDependencies": {
        ...
       "prettier": "^2.1.2",   // Just to make sure I have the latest and the greatest 
        ...
   }
```

2. Heroku stack: heroku-18 . It's the default and you have it unless your app is old.
3. I don't have these lines:

```
"cacheAjaxRequests": true,
"inlineCss": true,
"http2PushManifest": true,
```

I've heard that *"inlineCss": true,* may cause a problem

Comment: OMG thank you. I just spent hours as well trying to make this work!